# Resize 2D Real Number Vector

Tags: matlab, vector, resize

I have a vector of real numbers , its size is `256x1` ;

How can I resize it to become `mx4n` (where `m=256`, `n=256`) to be as the same exact size of my DNA matrix.

Can this be applied?

Comment: You mean to replicate it? You can use `repmat`

Answer (score 0):

As Adiel wrote in comment, if you want to replicate it n times, simply use MATLAB's repmat function.

```
n=256;
mat = rand(256,1);
out = repmat(mat,1,n);
```

Comment: The output of this will be a matrix , its size 256x256 , right? @Ibezito

Comment: True. if you want it to be mx4n, write repmat(mat,1,4*n)